# Product Lookup Not Showing Newer Products for Non-Admin

Tags: lookup, permissions, lookup-filter, product

I have a Product Lookup field on a custom object called Product Demos. I also recently imported a bunch of new products to the system. For some reason, the newer products aren't showing up in the lookup for non-admin users.

This feels like a permissions problem, but I can't imagine what, because the users can see the new Product detail pages without problem, or select Pricebook Entries for them for Opportunity Products.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they searching for the product? The default lookup only shows *recently used* items, not all items.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check security for the custom object **Product Demos*

You can check following things.

1. Record Type and Page layout. if there are multiple page layout then check if the field is assign to the particular page layout.
2. Field level Security - Check field level visibility in profile for particular object.

Please check and let me know.